# Relaunch application Xamarin Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

In order to apply settings to my application I need to close the application and restart it.

Is this possible to do with Xamarin.Mac

I am closing the app with

```
NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(this);
```

but don't know if it's possible to restart it again.

Comment: I use Sparkle with Xamarin.Mac to handle updates/restarts, you can look at this answer for how (in ObjC) Sparkle does it. Another example based on Sparkle's methods http://snipplr.com/view/3923/relaunch-an-application/